# How to delete an Excel file from a folder using Visual Basic code?

Tags: excel, vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2015

So I have a program that I am creating using Visual Basic through Visual Studio 2015.  Form based...I open Excel files, extract data, re-save new data.  But I cannot figure out how to delete Excel files....

Here are some code examples:

(open a blank template):

```
        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("File location")
```

(modify an existing excel file's data)

```
        'open the existing excel file
        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("c:\Images\" + qcComboBox.Text + ".xlsx")
```

So once I am done with the excel file how do I permanently delete it?

Comment: Depends. Are you using VB.NET or VBA?  They're 2 completely different languages, but the question is tagged with both.

Comment: `System.IO.File.Delete(fullpath)` .net only or `Kill(fullpath)` VBA and .Net

Comment: `Visual Basic through Visual Studio 2015` ...  vb.net. Plus `oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` wouldn't it need `Set` at the front in vba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of how you access your Excel document, it's still a document in the file system. Just delete your Excel document like this

```
System.IO.File.Delete(filename)
```

If you have tried `System.IO.File.Delete` without luck, maybe you aren't properly cleaning up the reference to the Excel document when you are done with it (common mistake). It is a COM object, and it is not managed by the CLR, unlike normal managed .NET objects. Here's how you can do that. Make a reference to COM >> `Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library` (or whatever version you have). And use this method.

```
Dim filename = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\test.xlsx"
Dim oExcel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
' The next line is necessary because you don't want to make a reference 
' to an unmanaged object two levels deep from an existing unmanaged object. 
' Otherwise you won't be able to clean it up properly
Dim oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks 
' don't do it this way, as described above
' Dim oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
Dim oBook = oBooks.Open(filename)

' close your objects, should be enough in most cases
oBook.Close()
oBooks.Close()
oExcel.Quit()

' should not need this but it's an added layer to ensure the objects aren't referenced to
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBook)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBooks)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oExcel)

' delete as usual
System.IO.File.Delete(filename)
```

Comment: It took me three days but I got it!  Yes sir, you were the most accurate when it comes to pointing me in the right direction.  It was being referenced to (something was holding the file hostage behind the scenes) so wasn't getting deleted.  Surprised because there were no errors or any indication that it wasn't successfully deleting from program until I checked the file folder.  Fixed, thanks!